# Adding 1pt Bar under navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I created a view like so and I want to position it right under my navigation bar but the constraint I added does nothing and keeps the bar all the way at the top of the view.

```
_navSeparator = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                 self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
_navSeparator.backgroundColor = 
                          [UIColor darkColorTheme];
[self.view addSubview:_navSeparator];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint 
      constraintWithItem:_navSeparator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:topGuide 
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

It has some arbitrary nav title.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use AutoLayout please set your view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` NO. Then the `Constraint` will work and frame will be useless.

So we should add full constraint(leading, top, trailing, height) like:

```
_navSeparator = [[UIView alloc] init];
_navSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_navSeparator.backgroundColor =
[UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview:_navSeparator];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_navSeparator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_navSeparator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_navSeparator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[_navSeparator addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:_navSeparator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:1.0]];
```

Moreover on iOS11+ please modify topGuide to `self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` because in the document we know

> Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of
>   topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor

Another thing is if you do want a view with 1pt height. You can set its height constraint's constant like `1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale`

Comment: safeAreaLayoutGuide only works with iOS 11, correct?

Comment: @humbleCoder Yes, it’s designed for iPhone X

Comment: So for people who don't have an iphone X won't see that? It worked btw. I used topLayoutGuide though.